# Javascript/jQuery how to reference created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I've been using buttons to create elements and then referencing the button clicked by using `this`. For example:

```
$(".addphoto").click(function(){
    photo_count++;
    $(this).parent().before("<label>Add Photo: <input type='file' name='photo[" + photo_count + "]'></label>");
    });
```

I wanted to do the same thing with a button that is created by the script, but since jQuery can only target elements that existed when it loaded, I targeted the `document` and used `.on()` instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".addphoto", function(){
    photo_count++;
    $(this).parent().before("<label>Add Photo: <input type='file' name='photo[" + photo_count + "]'></label>");
    });
```

The problem is that `this` now refers to `document` rather then the button that was just clicked. How do I reference that button?

Comment: no, `this` still refers to the clicked button

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PLk2G/1/

Comment: [that's event delegation and still this is the context of the addphoto](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: please provide your html

Comment: please share script to create buttons dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you give the original button an ID you can reference it using the .click() function.

HTML

```
<div class="x">
    <div>
        <button class="addphoto" id="addPhotoButton">addphoto</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (JQuery)

```
var photo_count = 0;
$('#addPhotoButton').click(function () {
    photo_count++;
    $(this).parent().before("<div><label>Add Photo: <input type='file' name='photo[" + photo_count + "]' id='addPhotoID_"+photo_count+"'></label></div>");
});
```

JSfiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/PLk2G/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try `.live()` instead of `.click()` method.

[Reference Link for live method.](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Edit: I'll add a short description.

`.live()` method attaches an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, **now and in the future.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(this)`, pass your event and reference `$(e.currentTarget)`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".addphoto", function(e){
    photo_count++;
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().before("<label>Add Photo: <input type='file' name='photo[" + photo_count + "]'></label>");
});
```